# How to say that I have done something in importance order in English?

Tags: word-usage

Is my sentence correct :

**I put the files based on their importance in the attached folder.**

The file structure should be something like that :

1- First file (Most important)

2- Second File ( Second most important)

3- Third File (Third most important)

Comment: *"I put (or insert) the files into the attached folder in order of importance."*

Comment: @Jeffrey, why not add it as an answer? Would quote your comment in the answer I'd make.

Comment: I didn't (strictly) answer the question "is my sentence correct", just offered an alternative :)

Comment: Well, there are two points I think, the first point is in the title and the second, in the body. :)

Answer (score 1):

Per Jeffrey's comment, you may use:

> "I put (or insert) the files into the attached folder **in order of importance."**

Also, you may opt to use:

> "... arranged according to importance..."

Kindly note that i**t is better to indicate that the first** [or the topmost, etc.] item is the most important in case the context is not clear.

So to consolidate:

> "I **arranged** the files **according to importance** in the attached folder, the first[topmost] file being the most important."

Answer (score 1):

*"based on their importance"*, on its own, is ambiguous in that sentence. It *could* mean that you choose, based on their importance, whether to put the files in the folder or not.

So, your sentence needs to make it clear that it is the *order* in which the files are placed that is being determined by their importance.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to other great answers, you could consider using the verb to [prioritize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prioritize) which means:

> to list or rate (as projects or goals) in order of priority

Your example:

> I have prioritized the files in the attached folder (as follows).

Or you could use to arrange in place of to put.

> I have arranged the files in order of priority in the attached folder (as follows).

Priority is better than importance when you try to list in order of priority.